# Webstorm ES6 named import getting cannot resolve symbol error

Tags: javascript, frontend, webstorm, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have an error in Webstorm when using ES6 named import declaration:

```
import { nodes } from 'utils/dom';
```

I get "cannot resolve symbol" error on "nodes"

Also when I try to export as named export like this:

```
export {
  write: document.write.bind(document),
  node: document.querySelector.bind(document),
  nodes: document.querySelectorAll.bind(document)
};
```

I get errors too.
I use eslint with babel-eslint parser.
The thing is that this works in Sublime Text 3 as a charm, but for some reason fails error checking in Webstorm.

I assume that this is because except Eslint webstorm is doing other code checking.

Any Idea how I can suppress that and use only eslint with babel-eslint parser?

Any advice will be appreciated

Comment: Your export is just wrong, that's not how exports work.  Not sure for the import though. What is `utils` in this case? That's not a standard path, since it is not a relative file path. Do you have custom module resolution logic somewhere?

Comment: Well you can export object and then import { property } from 'path' local variable property will be assigned with the value of exported property. Nothing wrong with the syntax. It works just fine. It does not supposed to be relative file path. I use webpack and babel loader. I don't need relative file path since I use moduleDirectories in webpack config to search in set of folders. So bottom line is that it works. And it's correct the question is why webstorm shows it as incorrect

Comment: @VladimirNovick How did you solve this problem then?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I get "cannot resolve symbol" error on "nodes"

is because `utils/dom` in standard Node code means "find dom.js inside a module called 'utils'. You have overridden this behavior by using webpack's `moduleDirectories` property, but WebStorm doesn't know what that is. For WebStorm to properly resolve `utils/dom`, you'll need to add the `utils` folder as a library in your webstorm project configuration.

Your `export` syntax is incorrect. ES6 import/export syntax is 100% unrelated to objects, and in your example export, you are using object syntax. `import { nodes }` is asking for an export named `nodes`. There are multiple ways that you could write the exports that you have:

```
export const write = document.write.bind(document);
export const node = document.querySelector.bind(document);
export const nodes = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
```

or alternatively you could collapse them if you like multiline `var/let/const`

```
export const write = document.write.bind(document),
    node = document.querySelector.bind(document),
    nodes = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
```

or even

```
const write = document.write.bind(document);
const node = document.querySelector.bind(document);
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);


export {write, node, nodes};
```

Answer (score 5):

Hard to say if this is directly related, but for **Webstorm** to know how to resolve your imports, you can also go to `Preferences > Directories` and set folders as `Resource Root` (or right/context-click on a folder and set it that way)

This might need to be done, for example, when you've configured **Webpack** to resolve certain sub-directories, where your project structure might be:

```
/
  /docs
  /src
    /containers
      /app
        App.js
    /components
      /header
        Header.js
```

In which case **Webstorm** would expect an import in `App.js` to look like the following:

```
import Header from '../../../components/header/Header'
```

Whereas with Webpack, if you've added `src` as a module to resolve, you can do the following, which **Webstorm** doesn't currently understand, hence adding it as a Resource Root *resolves* the issue

```
import Header from 'components/header/Header'
```

Reference: [Path aliases for imports in Webstorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943631/path-aliases-for-imports-in-webstorm)