# IntelliJ cannot resolve webpack aliased path

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, import, webpack

With webpack configuration it's possible to specify root of the resolving component:

```
resolve: {
  root: [ path.join(__dirname, './src/') ],
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.scss']
},
```

Now it is possible to import SASS file from `./src/` using tilde:

```
@import '~variables';
```

This import path will be resolved as `./src/variables` and everything works fine.

However IntelliJ doesn't recognize it properly and reports:

```
Cannot resolve file '~variables'
```

[image: Cannot resolve file '~variables']

Is it possible somehow to configure this IDE to add extra resolve path (by default it resolves only from `node_modules` directory)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With current version of Webstorm it is possible to set webpack configuration, which will enable recognize path aliases across the project:

[here is the answer where I specify how to set it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943631/path-aliases-for-imports-in-webstorm/45914938#45914938)

It recognize imports inside scss with tildes as well.

It works in my project where I also use webpack aliases and `scss` imports.
[image]

It was fixed with [this version.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25321)

Comment: Can you post the alias-part of your webpack config in here as well?