# Path aliases in WebStorm as in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, webstorm

We have file structure like

```
/common
    /src
        /componentA
        /componentB
```

And would like to use webpack aliases

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    common: 'common/src'
  }
}
```

to require modules like

```
require('common/componentA')
```

Is there any way to teach WebStorm to resolve this to save option by navigation using <kbd>Ctrl+Click</kbd>?

ResourceRoot option doesn't help for this case

Comment: I guess https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17254 and related tickets

Comment: see this answer https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22717#comment=27-1558931

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to get webstorm to read your webpack aliases, so you have to have 2 different "config setups" for this. Just means that you have to maintain webpack's alises and also webstorm's resources.

In webstorm just right click a folder and "Mark directory as" > "Resource root".

This is kind of a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943631/path-aliases-for-imports-in-webstorm) and there's [a better answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943631/path-aliases-for-imports-in-webstorm#37135031).

Comment: i have mentioned that resource root solution doesn't work cause i need real alias WITHOUT saving inner folder structure. This question is not a duplication

Comment: it's kind of a duplicate since in the other answer thread it's kind of explained. although it doesn't mention custom aliases like yours. my use of "kind of" is quite loose..

Comment: i did misunderstand the way you were using aliases too, now i understand what you were asking. so sorry about that! although i still think it's not possible.

Comment: i'm pretty sure it is not possible, but maybe)

Comment: maybe.. hopefully :3

Comment: I just noticed Webstorm already implemented module resolution. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-webpack.html#webpack_module_resolution

Answer (score 1):

Since Webstorm 2017.2 you can set webpack config file and it will recognize you aliases:

[image]