# Flow and webpack aliases

Tags: node.js, webpack

I have troubles with flow erros.

```
import {Button} from "components/basics/Button";
```

'Module is not installed'

webpack:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {components: path.resolve(__dirname,'../../src/main/js/components'),}
}
```

flowconfig is outise the **src** folder

I added this to flowconfig

```
[options]
module.name_mapper='^components\/\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/main/js/components/\1'
module.name_mapper='^components' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/main/js/components'
```

But it is not helps.

Application is work.
No errors with the build. No errors with the flow console. 
But IDE highlighted my `import` with error. 
Maybe it is problem with IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1):

It was not flow or webpack config problem. It was IntelliJ (Webpack) setup.
So to remove this error you should do that described here

[Path aliases for imports in WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943631/path-aliases-for-imports-in-webstorm/45914938#45914938)