# NodeJS relative import using `@` - Module is not installed in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I am working on a project created by others in Node.JS.

Noticed a pattern I've never used before.
All the inside imports are used with `@`.

ex: `import Config from '@config/config';`

Where config is a file inside `/src/config/config.js`.

Now, it's working flowlessly but WebStorm keeps complain about `Module is not installed` and suggest me to `Install @config/config as dev dependency`. 
The real issue behind it is that WebStorm isn't able to autocomplete or help me in any other way regard those imports.

And how do I configure WebStorm to understand this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a webpack config file in the project? Does WebStorm know about it? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943631/path-aliases-for-imports-in-webstorm

Comment: @AurelBílý no webpack here. it's only backend project with one route that doesn't serve anything to frontend

Comment: Is there any other config then? Is the code pre-processed by a framework?

Comment: @AurelBílý express.js