# How to enable support for SvelteKit's $lib alias in WebStorm (and PhpStorm, etc)?

Tags: webstorm, svelte, jetbrains-ide, sveltekit

Is it possible to define a special mapping that enables PhpStorm (or other WebStorm based IDEs) to have the ability to find files located in SvelteKit's special [`$lib` directory alias](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$lib)?

For example, in PhpStorm, I'm importing global styles like so:

```
<script context="module">
    import '$lib/global-styles.scss';
</script>
```

However, the IDE unfortunately displays "Cannot find declaration to go to" when attempting to navigate to that particular file:

[image: Popup error displaying "Cannot find declaration to go to"]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems the fix was reasonably easy (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59369029/899075)). Just add a path alias to any JS file in the root of your project called `.webstorm.js` (filename isn't important):

```js
// eslint-disable
System.config({
    "paths": {
        "$lib/*": "./src/lib/*",
    }
});
```

Now navigation to paths under `$lib/*` should "just work" ✨ automatically. Unfortunately I can't find documentation for this special WebStorm-specific `System.config()` workaround, the best I could find was [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22717#focus=streamItem-27-1558931-0-0) on Jetbrains' issue tracker.

---

**Edit (May 2, 2023):** Also, for TypeScript support, use the method suggested in [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76129512/899075) by Tyrone which may have [broader support](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) outside of just Jetbrains IDEs

Comment: For me, it doesn't work

Comment: @polRk Can you provide more details about what IDE you're using, what you tried and what is happening?

Comment: Did not work for me either (using Webstorm)

Comment: Worked on PHPStorm with .phpstorm.js file

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue but resolved it (since I am using Typescript) by adding a paths entry in my `./tsconfig.json` at the root of my project.

```
{
  // ...
  "compilerOptions": {
      "paths": {
          "$lib/*": ["src/lib/*"],
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: That's great, thanks Tyrone. That works for me in PhpStorm as well. I'll drop this into my answer and credit you!

Comment: p.s. Thanks for editing, my intent was to call attention to your answer.  Updating it to actually link to your answer as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add `baseUrl` in tsconfig.json of your project:

```
{
"extends": "./.svelte-kit/tsconfig.json",
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": "./src"
}
```