# Go to function definition in PhpStorm, requires certain format to work for React Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, phpstorm

I have a list of components like this:

```txt
tsconfig.json
src/
  ui/
    atoms/
      - index.ts
      - tooltop.tsx
      - button.tsx
    molecules/
      - index.ts
      - input.tsx
```

In `atoms/index.ts` I have exported all my components like this:

```js
export * from './tooltip';
export * from './button';
```

And in `input.tsx` I have the problem, where I can't CMD+Click on the component name to go to the component.

**My `input.tsx`-component:**

```js
import { Tooltip } from "../atoms";

const Input = ({ tooltipDescription, }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {tooltipDescription && <Tooltip description={tooltipDescription} />}
      <input value="some value" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

If I here CMD-click on "<Tooltip" from this line: `{tooltipDescription && <Tooltip ...}` then PhpStorm links me to the import statement in the top (!!). And if I CMD-click on the import-statement, then it links me back down to the use of the component, in the same file (!!).

What is extra-weird is that I can see that the relative path: `import { Tooltip } from "../atoms";` and the CMD-click does work in VSCode.

### My question

Is this a bug or intended use?
And can I adjust this somehow (via some settings), so the relative path works?

---

### Solution attempt 1: Try different import-formats

I can see, that the CMD-click on the "<Tooltip"-part works, if the import is written like this:

```js
import { Tooltip } from "../atoms/tooltip";
```

... Directly to the file, so that is expected to work.
But also this:

```js
import { Tooltip } from "@src/ui/atoms";
```

Using the `path` from my tsconfig.json. This perplexes me!
Why does this work, when my relative path doesn't?

### Solution attempt 2: Invalidate caches and restart IDE

I tried to go to `File` >> `Invalidate caches...`, and tick everything off (to remove all temp-files) and then restart my IDE. After several minutes of reindexing stuff, it still behaved in the same way.

### Solution attempt 3: Mark root as resource root

I tried doing what was suggested here: [Marking root as resource root](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37135031/1766219). It didn't change anything.

### Solution attempt 4: Consider what is actually making the connection

So when I CMD-click on the component and what to go to the `.tsx`-file, then there must be something that helps PhpStorm make that connection. I'm using Vite for bundling and compiling assets. So I considered if I needed some "Vite plugin" such as this: [Vite integrated](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16897-vite-integrated). I didn't install it, since it seems like quite the big thing, to install an entire third-party plugin, just to get this to work.

And I wonder if this is why the import via `@src/ui/atoms` works, since it may then use some TypeScript mapping (or eslint mapping). Hmm..!

---

### Versions

- `PhpStorm 2022.2.5`, `Build #PS-222.4554.13, built on March 17, 2023`
- Macbook Pro, intel chip, Sonoma 14.0.

Comment: What does your tsconfig.json look like?